# ggplot labeling horizontal line appearing over 2 facets (x axis is dates, middle section removed)

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, annotate

I am creating a plot of `y=results` `x=Date`. There is a large period of time that I do not want to plot so have split the plot into 2 facets, excluding the dates not needed.

**I want a horizontal line over both facets, but the label "Normal limit" only on the first.**

Is this possible?

```
df = data%>%
  filter((Date >= dmy("25/03/2011") & Date <= dmy("18/05/2012")) |  #filter unwanted data
           (Date >= dmy("18/07/2019") & Date <= dmy("28/04/2020") ))%>%
  mutate(bin = Date >= dmy("18/07/2019")) # define the cut point where I want data to be shown

plot = ggplot(df, aes(Date, Result))+
  geom_point(colour = "red3", size = 2.5)+
  geom_line( colour= "purple4", size = 1)+
  facet_wrap(bin ~ ., scale = 'free_x')+
  scale_x_date(date_labels =  "%b %Y",guide = guide_axis(angle = 45), date_breaks = "2 months")+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,6.2, by=0.5))+
  theme(strip.text.x = element_blank())+ # this removes the true/false bin identification
  geom_vline(xintercept = dmy("29/8/2011"), linetype="dashed", 
             color = "black", size=1, )+
geom_vline(xintercept = dmy("26/1/2012"), linetype="longdash", 
           color = "black", size=1, )+
  geom_vline(xintercept = dmy("16/9/19"), linetype="dashed", 
             color = "black", size=1, )+
  geom_vline(xintercept = dmy("7/11/19"), linetype="longdash", 
             color = "black", size=1, )+
  geom_hline(yintercept =0.4, linetype="dotted", 
             color = "black", size=1, )+
  annotate(y= 0.4, x = dmy("01/5/11"), label="Normal Limit", geom = "label")
```

Which produces this plot:
[image]

This is how I'd like plot to appear, but with "Normal limit" label on left hand facet only:
[image]

This is the `data`:

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(Date = structure(c(18873, 18843, 18766, 18746, 
18745, 18738, 18705, 18691, 18688, 18645, 18583, 18549, 18541, 
18509, 18502, 18457, 18435, 18381, 18380, 18362, 18320, 18276, 
18232, 18219, 18207, 18199, 18195, 18194, 18190, 18184, 18180, 
18177, 18164, 18152, 18148, 18127, 18108, 18095, 18066, 18038, 
18016, 17988, 17948, 17919, 17875, 17858, 17830, 17802, 17763, 
17732, 17704, 17689, 17669, 17646, 17618, 17583, 17557, 17520, 
17487, 17443, 17400, 17381, 17373, 17368, 17340, 17312, 17284, 
17249, 17232, 17228, 17207, 17196, 17186, 17134, 17105, 17088, 
17078, 17043, 17037, 17032, 17016, 17008, 16986, 16951, 16930, 
16915, 16910, 16878, 16860, 16812, 16766, 16729, 16715, 16701, 
16689, 16674, 16671, 16668, 16661, 16657, 16643, 16640, 16581, 
16561, 16524, 16489, 16443, 16402, 16365, 16344, 16310, 16304, 
16286, 16255, 16224, 16204, 16189, 16175, 16160, 16150, 16141, 
16127, 16120, 16105, 16090, 16077, 16069, 16057, 16057, 16048, 
16041, 16034, 16024, 16021, 16014, 16008, 16002, 15996, 15993, 
15988, 15981, 15975, 15973, 15964, 15940, 15926, 15908, 15883, 
15875, 15870, 15861, 15849, 15845, 15838, 15835, 15832, 15828, 
15828, 15826, 15819, 15819, 15798, 15783, 15765, 15715, 15674, 
15660, 15635, 15602, 15593, 15572, 15552, 15517, 15489, 15478, 
15455, 15427, 15399, 15380, 15365, 15364, 15362, 15355, NA, 15308, 
15273, 15260, 15250, 15230, 15226, 15180, 15175, 15154, 15114, 
15082, 15058, 15028, 14995, 14973, 14935, 14911, 14879, 14837, 
14816, 14790, 14757, 14727, 14697, 14666, 14607, 14580, 14536, 
14517, 14480, 14452, 14391, 14363, 14328, 14295, 14272, 14207, 
14174, 14146, 14118, 14081, 14055, 14022, 13992, 13845, 13817, 
13782, 13719, 13691, 13661), class = "Date"), Result = c(0.1, 
0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 1, 1, 1.2, 1.3, 0.9, 1.1, 
1.2, 1, 0.8, 0.6, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 
0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 
0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 
0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.33, 0.29, 0.25, 0.25, 0.29, 0.36, 0.16, 
0.18, 0.36, 0.29, 0.26, 0.24, 0.25, 0.33, 0.22, 0.34, 0.39, 0.4, 
0.22, 0.3, 0.29, 0.31, 0.29, 0.37, 0.85, 0.52, 0.29, 0.37, 0.4, 
0.4, 0.43, 0.4, 0.32, 0.27, 0.18, 0.27, 0.2, 0.18, 0.22, 0.26, 
0.28, 0.27, 0.18, 0.18, 0.21, 0.21, 0.23, 0.16, 0.21, 0.21, 0.2, 
0.28, 0.39, 0.27, 0.34, 0.37, 0.31, 0.33, 0.42, 0.25, 0.31, 0.31, 
0.23, 0.31, 0.33, 0.4, 0.47, 0.46, 1.19, 2.51, 4.62, 5.57, 2.8, 
6.05, NA, 1.21, 0.56, 0.21, 0.34, 0.72, 0.72, 0.24, 0.28, 0.25, 
0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.22, 0.29, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 
0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 
0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 
0.24, 0.32, 0.2)), row.names = c(NA, -234L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: @akrun I know that, thanks. But I don't know what I need to do differently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with facet-wise annotations is that `annotate()` do not take a `data` argument wherein facetting variables can be looked up. Instead, I suggest you use a regular `geom_label()` layer, wherein the `data` argument contains the facetting variable. Simplified example below:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

# data <- structure(...) # As per example data
# df <- data %>% filter(...) # As per example code

ggplot(df, aes(Date, Result)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(bin ~ ., scale = "free_x") +
  geom_label(
    data = data.frame(bin = FALSE),
    aes(x = dmy("01/5/11"), y = 0.4, label = "Normal\nLimits")
  )
```

[image]

Comment: That's a great solution! I like this way better than my workaround - awesome!

Answer (score 1):

I've tangled with this issue before and the best solution I found was to use grid graphics to overlay my annotations, e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'gridExtra'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     combine

df1 <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(18873, 18843, 18766, 18746, 
                                         18745, 18738, 18705, 18691, 18688, 18645, 18583, 18549, 18541, 
                                         18509, 18502, 18457, 18435, 18381, 18380, 18362, 18320, 18276, 
                                         18232, 18219, 18207, 18199, 18195, 18194, 18190, 18184, 18180, 
                                         18177, 18164, 18152, 18148, 18127, 18108, 18095, 18066, 18038, 
                                         18016, 17988, 17948, 17919, 17875, 17858, 17830, 17802, 17763, 
                                         17732, 17704, 17689, 17669, 17646, 17618, 17583, 17557, 17520, 
                                         17487, 17443, 17400, 17381, 17373, 17368, 17340, 17312, 17284, 
                                         17249, 17232, 17228, 17207, 17196, 17186, 17134, 17105, 17088, 
                                         17078, 17043, 17037, 17032, 17016, 17008, 16986, 16951, 16930, 
                                         16915, 16910, 16878, 16860, 16812, 16766, 16729, 16715, 16701, 
                                         16689, 16674, 16671, 16668, 16661, 16657, 16643, 16640, 16581, 
                                         16561, 16524, 16489, 16443, 16402, 16365, 16344, 16310, 16304, 
                                         16286, 16255, 16224, 16204, 16189, 16175, 16160, 16150, 16141, 
                                         16127, 16120, 16105, 16090, 16077, 16069, 16057, 16057, 16048, 
                                         16041, 16034, 16024, 16021, 16014, 16008, 16002, 15996, 15993, 
                                         15988, 15981, 15975, 15973, 15964, 15940, 15926, 15908, 15883, 
                                         15875, 15870, 15861, 15849, 15845, 15838, 15835, 15832, 15828, 
                                         15828, 15826, 15819, 15819, 15798, 15783, 15765, 15715, 15674, 
                                         15660, 15635, 15602, 15593, 15572, 15552, 15517, 15489, 15478, 
                                         15455, 15427, 15399, 15380, 15365, 15364, 15362, 15355, NA, 15308, 
                                         15273, 15260, 15250, 15230, 15226, 15180, 15175, 15154, 15114, 
                                         15082, 15058, 15028, 14995, 14973, 14935, 14911, 14879, 14837, 
                                         14816, 14790, 14757, 14727, 14697, 14666, 14607, 14580, 14536, 
                                         14517, 14480, 14452, 14391, 14363, 14328, 14295, 14272, 14207, 
                                         14174, 14146, 14118, 14081, 14055, 14022, 13992, 13845, 13817, 
                                         13782, 13719, 13691, 13661), class = "Date"), Result = c(0.1, 
                                                                                                  0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
                                                                                                  0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 1, 1, 1.2, 1.3, 0.9, 1.1, 
                                                                                                  1.2, 1, 0.8, 0.6, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 
                                                                                                  0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 
                                                                                                  0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
                                                                                                  0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
                                                                                                  0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
                                                                                                  0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 
                                                                                                  0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.33, 0.29, 0.25, 0.25, 0.29, 0.36, 0.16, 
                                                                                                  0.18, 0.36, 0.29, 0.26, 0.24, 0.25, 0.33, 0.22, 0.34, 0.39, 0.4, 
                                                                                                  0.22, 0.3, 0.29, 0.31, 0.29, 0.37, 0.85, 0.52, 0.29, 0.37, 0.4, 
                                                                                                  0.4, 0.43, 0.4, 0.32, 0.27, 0.18, 0.27, 0.2, 0.18, 0.22, 0.26, 
                                                                                                  0.28, 0.27, 0.18, 0.18, 0.21, 0.21, 0.23, 0.16, 0.21, 0.21, 0.2, 
                                                                                                  0.28, 0.39, 0.27, 0.34, 0.37, 0.31, 0.33, 0.42, 0.25, 0.31, 0.31, 
                                                                                                  0.23, 0.31, 0.33, 0.4, 0.47, 0.46, 1.19, 2.51, 4.62, 5.57, 2.8, 
                                                                                                  6.05, NA, 1.21, 0.56, 0.21, 0.34, 0.72, 0.72, 0.24, 0.28, 0.25, 
                                                                                                  0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.22, 0.29, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 
                                                                                                  0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 
                                                                                                  0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 
                                                                                                  0.24, 0.32, 0.2)), row.names = c(NA, -234L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                         "tbl", "data.frame"))

df <- df1 %>%
  filter((Date >= dmy("25/03/2011") & Date <= dmy("18/05/2012")) |  #filter unwanted data
           (Date >= dmy("18/07/2019") & Date <= dmy("28/04/2020") ))%>%
  mutate(bin = ifelse(Date >= dmy("18/07/2019"), "yes", "no"))

plot = ggplot(df, aes(Date, Result))+
  geom_point(colour = "red3", size = 2.5)+
  geom_line( colour= "purple4", size = 1)+
  facet_wrap(bin ~ ., scale = 'free_x')+
  scale_x_date(date_labels =  "%b %Y",guide = guide_axis(angle = 45), date_breaks = "2 months")+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,6.2, by=0.5))+
  theme(strip.text.x = element_blank()) + # this removes the true/false bin identification
   geom_vline(xintercept = dmy("29/8/2011"), linetype="dashed", 
              color = "black", size=1) +
   geom_vline(xintercept = dmy("26/1/2012"), linetype="longdash", 
              color = "black", size=1)+
   geom_vline(xintercept = dmy("16/9/19"), linetype="dashed", 
              color = "black", size=1)+
   geom_vline(xintercept = dmy("7/11/19"), linetype="longdash", 
              color = "black", size=1)+
   geom_hline(yintercept =0.4, linetype="dotted", 
              color = "black", size=1)
  # annotate(y= 0.4, x = dmy("01/5/11"), label="Normal Limit", geom = "label")
gtext <- grid::textGrob("Normal Limit", x = unit(0.15, "npc"), y = unit(0.25, "npc"))
gcombined <- grid::grobTree(ggplotGrob(plot), gtext)
grid.arrange(gcombined)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Would this be suitable for your problem?

Comment: thanks. Yes that works. I've accepted @teunbrand answer as it was simpler for me